# Javascript Loop to Call a Function

Tags: javascript, loops, onmouseover, onmouseout

Trying to figure out onmouseover, onmouseout and onclick with several pictures all having the same ID tag.  To do that, I understand I need a .length loop.

This code works without the length loop...

```
window.onload = setPictures;
function setPictures() {
    var img = document.getElementById("pictureBox");
        img.onmouseover = mouseOverImage;
        img.onmouseout= mouseOutImage; 
}
function mouseOverImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    img.style.opacity = .5;
}
function mouseOutImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    img.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

This is the loop function I attempted that is not working.

```
window.onload = setPictures;
function setPictures() {
   var img = document.getElementById("pictureBox");
   for (var i=0; i<img.length; i++) {       
      img[i].onmouseover = mouseOverImage;
      img[i].onmouseout= mouseOutImage;}
 }
```

Please advise, and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single Element... Not a collection...

Comment: You should never have more than one id tag per element

Comment: And since everyone is telling you not to use `ID` they should at least let ya know that `class` would be the better tag.

Comment: @IsabelInc More than good practice. It's *invalid* to have the same ID assigned to multiple elements.

Comment: You're trying to loop over a single element. If you wish to get all elements of a tag, use [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). Or, better still, via a specific class using [getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` only returns one element, as ID's should be unique.

Instead, add a class to each element and select them by class. Callbacks can rely on `this`'s context for your mouse events:

```
function mouseOverImage() {
    this.style.opacity = .5;
}
function mouseOutImage() {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
}

window.onload = function setPictures() {
    var imageCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('pictureBox');
    for (var i=0; i < imageCollection.length; i++) {       
        imageCollection[i].onmouseover = mouseOverImage;
        imageCollection[i].onmouseout = mouseOutImage;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, getElementById return only one element.
This below could help you:

```
window.onload = setPictures;
    function setPictures() {
       var img = document.getElementById("pictureBox0");
       for (var i=1; img != null; i++) {       
          img.onmouseover = mouseOverImage;
          img.onmouseout= mouseOutImage;
          img = document.getElementById("pictureBox"+i);
       }
     }
```